# Updating two different fields using Enzime Mount

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I built a component that changes document title whenever the user changes one of those fields - first name and last name.

Then, trying to write a test case for this scenario, I tried the following solution (simulating a change event in each of the input fields):

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ComponentToBeTested from './ComponentToBeTested';

import Enzyme, {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

it('Should update page title to the value of the inputs ( name + lastName) when it changes', ()=>{
  const wrapper = mount(<ComponentToBeTested />);
  const name = wrapper.find('#name');
  const lastName = wrapper.find('#lastName');
  name.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Always' } });
  lastName.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Test' } });
  
  expect(document.title).toBe('Always Test');
});
```

However, this test is failing with the message : 
Expected: "Always Test" | Received: "Always First"

It seems that only the first value updates.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

ps.: My component code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ConponentToBeTested () {

    const name = useFormInput('Test')
    const lastName = useFormInput('First');

    useDocumentTitle(name.value + ' ' + lastName.value);
    
    return (
        <div className="component-to-be-tested">
            <input id="name" {...name}  />
            <input id="lastName" {...lastName} />
        </div>
    )
}
function useDocumentTitle(title) {
    useEffect(() => {
      document.title =  title;
    });
  }
  
  function useFormInput (initialValue) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  
    function handleChange(e) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }
  
    return {
      value,
      onChange : handleChange
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no `onChange` event added to your inputs. And as you use `useState` I think you need to call `wrapper.update()` as well.

Comment: ...and `useEffect` is async so you need to add something like `await Promise.resolve()` to flush microtasks queue prior checking result.

Comment: So far, I added a setTimeout wrapper to my expect statement, but I know its not the best solution. 

`setTimeout( () => {expect(document.title).toBe('Always Test')} , 1); `